# Jquery ajax post doesn't send data to server end(Using PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

**HTML**

```
<a id="1">Add to notebook</a>
<a id="2">Add to notebook</a>
<a id="3">Add to notebook</a>
<a id="4">Add to notebook</a>
...
<a id="40">Add to notebook</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //callback handler for post submit
    $("a").click(function(e)
    {
        var vocab_id = $(this).attr("id");
        var formURL = 'http://localhost/test/test.php';
        $.ajax(
        {
            url : formURL,
            type: "POST",
            data : vocab_id,
            dataType : "text",
        });
        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
        //e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
    });
});
</script>
```

I have a list of hyperlinks, it will send the currently clicked value of id to the server end by clicking the respective link.

But the problem is

1. Back-end doesn't receive any post data at all.
2. People said that I should uncomment the e.unbind() to stop multiple submit, but I got error after that line was uncommented. Error message is like this.

**`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 2:479(anonymous function) 2:479n.event.dispatch jquery-1.11.0.js:3r.handle`**

Comment: data part shoulbe either `data :{ name : vocab_id }` or `data : "name="+vocab_id`

Comment: What are you seeing in the php error log or in FireBug, or whatever your browser uses to display status?

Comment: @PranavCBalan thank you,that solved my first problem,but why the e.unbind went wrong

Comment: @Len_D Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function,this error message shown in my chrome console panel

Comment: use `$( this ).unbind( e );` , it will unbind the object from current event handler

Comment: Kindly add this code in $.ajax to debug to check if ajax request fails


error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
}

Comment: @PranavCBalan thank you so much this really solved my problem,but i'm not for sure whether this unbind() method is really needed or not.It works anyway.

Comment: If you want to submit form only once then use it , else leave it as a comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data part in **[`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)** should be like either

```
data :{ name : vocab_id }
```

or

```
data : "name="+vocab_id
```

Syntax for **[`unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)** is not correct use the following

```
$(this).unbind(e);
```

it will unbind the object from current event handler